# subsections do not appear in the general index

Tags: indexing

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue,breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %para poder navegar a travez de nuestras referencias dentro de nuestro documento. Este hipertexto estará resaltado con color
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow} % para combinar filas o columnas en las tablas
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable} % para tablas extensas en varias páginas
%\usepackage{hyperref} % cuando te unique en la referencia aparece la manito y te lleva a la unidad secional
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt} % espacio debajo de las tablas

\usepackage{array} % para insertar matrices
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varioref}
%\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\setlength{\parindent} {4.3em}   % para aumentar la sangria de cada inicio de párrafo.
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


%
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty % para que cada pagina de cada capitulo no se enumere
\makeatother
%

%%%editar encabezados
\chead[]{}
% primera pagina de un capitulo
%\usepackage{fancyheadings}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{
%   \fancyhead[L]{}
%   \fancyhead[C]{}
%   \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
%   \fancyfoot[L]{}
%   \fancyfoot[C]{}
%   \fancyfoot[R]{}
%   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%}
%quitar número de pagina del pie de pagína
\cfoot[]{}



%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\scriptsize \leftmark}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize \rightmark}

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
%


\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\author{Dennis Edquen Fenández}
\title{Tesis}


\begin{document}
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \frontmatter
    %caratula}
    \include{caratula}
    
    %Dedicatoria    
    \include{dedicatoria}
    
    %Agradecimiento     
    \include{agradecimiento}
    
    %Índice
    \tableofcontents
    
    % Tablas
    \listoftables

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \mainmatter
    %Introducción   
    \include{capitulos/introduccion}
    
    % Marco Teórico 
    \include{capitulos/marco-teorico}
    
    % Marco Metodológico    
    \include{capitulos/marco-metodologico}
    
    %Teoría de la Medida    
    %\include{teormedida}
    
    %Algebra Lineal 
    %\include{alglineal}
    
    %Aplicaciones   
    %\include{aplicaciones} 
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \backmatter
    
    %Apéndice
    
    %Bibliografía

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: By "General Index", do you mean the Table of Contents?

Comment: What happens if you insert the instruction `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` (to use the same counter value as `secnumdepth`) and recompile the document twice?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you load the `setspace` package, running `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` is rather poor practice. Try `\setstretch{1.5}` instead.

Comment: `book` has `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` so by default sections and subsections will be in the toc not subsubsections, you can increase this a Mico comments above